# Spring boot 2 actuator cache Metrics with client-server Hazelcast cluster

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cache

I have spring boot 2 application accessing remote Hazelcast cluster usign spring-boot-starter-cache & spring-boot-autoconfigure.

Caches are created through spring-cache annotations.

We observe /actuator/prometheus endpoint does include the cache metrics(cache hits, puts, gets, etc) for our caches and cacheManager, but it always shows reading as 0.0.

I deep dived into implementation and noticed it is designed to capture metrics for local hazelcast member.

```java
/**
 * @return The number of hits against cache entries hold in this local partition. Not all gets had to result from
 * a get operation against {@link #cache}. If a get operation elsewhere in the cluster caused a lookup against an entry
 * held in this partition, the hit will be recorded against map stats in this partition and not in the map stats of the
 * calling {@link IMap}.
 */
@Override
protected long hitCount() {
    return cache.getLocalMapStats().getHits();
}
```

Any idea/suggestion to capture metrics for my deployment model (Hazelcast as client-server)? is it possible to get prometheus metrics for hazelcast server member with spring boot autoconfigure in this model ?

UPDATE:
I am able to get cache metrics on hazelcast member(server) by starting it with spring boot 2, micrometer-prometheus jar on classpath.

Comment: Did your update answer the question ?

Comment: Well, partially. What I am looking for a metrics on how clients perceive the cache. It should include the network latency and serialization overhead.